# Resolve conflict on pull in Atom

Tags: git, atom-editor

When I pull and there is a conflict in Atom, the file with the conflict markers and a detached Branch ist created.

After I resolved the conflict, I get stuck. I tried "Create detached commit", but how to go on? When I go back to master and push git still says that the tip of my current branch is behind remote. When I Pull, it says

```
It seems that there is already a rebase-apply directory, and
I wonder if you are in the middle of another rebase.  If that is the
case, please try
    git rebase (--continue | --abort | --skip)
If that is not the case, please
    rm -fr "C:/Users/ststolz/git/test/.git/rebase-apply"
and run me again.  I am stopping in case you still have something
valuable there.
```

When I now try `git rebase --continue` in Command Line, git says:

```
No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?
If there is nothing left to stage, chances are that something else
already introduced the same changes; you might want to skip this patch.

When you have resolved this problem, run "git rebase --continue".
If you prefer to skip this patch, run "git rebase --skip" instead.
To check out the original branch and stop rebasing, run "git rebase --abort".
```

I also tried to rebase the detached branch to master. Here I also get the message "It seems that ...". When doing `git rebase --continue` while on detached branch, I get again "No changes - did you ...".

How should I resolve this in Atom? I have no further ideas.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Clone a new project in two different directories D1 and D2
2. Create text file with text "ab"
3. Pull this in both directories D1 and D2
4. Change "`ab`" to "`a_b_`" in D2 and commit with 'make b cursive'
5. Change "`a_b_`" to "`a**_b_**`" in D2 and commit with 'make b bold'
6. Push Changes
7. Change "`ab`" to "`_a_b`" in D1 and commit with 'make a cursive'
8. Change "`_a_b`" to "`**_a_**b`" in D1 and commit with 'make a bold'
9. Push Changes
10. Pull because of conflict
11. Resolve conflict so that the resulting text is "`**_a_****_b_**`"
12. now I am stuck like described in text above

Comment: You are probably running "git pull --rebase", not just "git pull"? Because normal pull merges, and your messages are about rebase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No changes - did you forget to use 'git add'?

You seem to have resolved the conflicts so that you removed all your local edits. Is it something you really meant? If so, then call `git rebase --skip` as it is suggesting.

Edit: following your description - you are rebasing (?) 2 commits `A1` and `A2`, which edit the "a".

- First just adds cusrive to a, and it conflicts.
- (I assume) at that step you edited it to `**_a_****_b_**`, added and continued the 
  rebase,
- git records first rebased commit `A1'` second commit also conflicts
- (I assume) you, again, edit the file to `**_a_****_b_**` and run `git rebase --continue`
- here, the `file`'s content is same as in `A1'`, and you get the message "No changes..."
- You can run  the `git rebase --skip`, skipping the A2, because all your changes already recorded in the commit `A1'`.
- Alternatively, you can restart the rebase, and resolve the first commit only as `_a_**_b_**`, and the second as `**_a_****_b_**`, so that you preserve the history of "a" formatting

Comment: When pushing is not possible because of remote changes and I get conflicts when pulling, I want to resolve the conflicts to be able to push my local edits. This is what I meant. Is the normal way to do so, to resolve conflicts an then call `git rebase --skip`?

Comment: The message "No changes...." means that your staged state is same as HEAD. Getting it during rebase means that either your changes already exist in base, or you resolved conflicts by chosing the base version.

Comment: No, what I did, was to merge both versions. So it was not like the base version. I try to give the exact steps to reproduce in my question.

Comment: Thanks to your help I found the answer. On the command line all worked fine. First: My global config was set to use rebase on pull. Thats why atom went into rebase. But rebase seems to be not fully implemented in the moment. So the only thing you can do (what I found out), is to make changes, stage them and then call `git rebase --continue` on command line. In atom the only chance is a "detached commit" and then you get stuck like I did. I am happy for comments if I am wrong. Merge worked like a charm within atom.